# Chopped edge around border of image

Tags: ios

I have an image with a border

```
let smallicon: UIImageView = {
    let smallicon = UIImageView()
    smallicon.layer.borderWidth = 2
    smallicon.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    smallicon.hidden = true
    return smallicon
}()
```

The problem is that is has tiny chopped edge around border (small image with yellow and black lines)

[image]

How to get rid of it ?

Comment: Try `smallicon.layer.masksToBounds = true`.

Comment: tried, doesn't work

Comment: Why does your border is a circle? Layers are rectangles by default.

Answer (score 1):

Solution

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Create a view with red background for demonstration
    let v = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100))
    v.center = view.center
    v.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    view.addSubview(v)

    // Add rounded corners
    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    maskLayer.frame = v.bounds
    maskLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: v.bounds, byRoundingCorners: .TopRight | .TopLeft, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 25, height: 25)).CGPath
    v.layer.mask = maskLayer

    // Add border
    let borderLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    borderLayer.path = maskLayer.path // Reuse the Bezier path
    borderLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
    borderLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.greenColor().CGColor
    borderLayer.lineWidth = 5
    borderLayer.frame = v.bounds
    v.layer.addSublayer(borderLayer)   
}
```

}

NOTE! in order this to work target view must have `frame` property setup with size. without size your view will not be seen at all